# add inline css for "td img"

Tags: html, css

I have a requirement where I need to add special styling to `img` that are inside `td`

```
td img {
 max-width:100%;
 height:auto;
}
```

I need this to be inline and not inside css file. How to achieve this ?

> I am not going for css file because I am working on RichText editor. I need to insert img inside table. The same html page will later be rendered on different sites, so I want inline property to display consistent table style.

or **can I add some inline style on `td` itself that the img or anything else doesn't overflow** ?

Comment: <element style="max-width: 100%; height: auto"></element>

Comment: Can you provide a snippet?

Comment: why would you want inline css? It's bad practice that leads to hard-to maintain code, only time it should really be used is for injecting php (or another server-side language) - oh and JS DOM stuff

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs : because its a piece of html that I need to generate in RichText editor and pass on to different sites. I want it to be consistent

Comment: @Samuel it's  better to keep as much CSS in css files as possible and have stray inline css rather than full site inline css

Comment: @VXp: Please check my above comment. I cant do that as I need to provide this feature to specific tables. The img can be inserted outside table or inside table. I want my table to have this css

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs: I agree but in this case I cant rely on other css which will be there on other sites where my `html` code will be rendered. So definitely inline is the best chioce here

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can inline the element like @VXp said. If you are getting the information from PHP and you want to inline all your tables, you probably need to do that in PHP.

Comment: Anyway, if you want it to be in an HTML file, you can use `<style>` tags. I don't see the problem here.

Comment: Your edit makes it sound like the actual issue is something else than what you said at first. So let's take it from the start: what are you trying to do exactly and what happens that you don't want to happen?

Comment: Then use the internal styling with the <style> tag, like in the answer below and put that on every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add css styles in the `<style>` tag directly in your HTML

```
<!-- other elements -->
<style>td img {max-width:100%;height:auto;}</style>
<!-- other elements -->
```

Comment: but wont it affect other `img` & `td` pairs which are outside my `html` text ? as this style will be added to the entire `site` page where my `html` will be rendered ?

Comment: Yes but if you want to specify the selector more just do it by adding an id or class to the `<td>` or over it and use the selector in the style

Answer (score 0):

You can use  css styles like these

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="link" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```